# Debug multithreaded CTest

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb, ctest

We have a legacy code and now trying to upgrade compile from c++98 to c++14 and as a part of the process some unit tests are failing when compiled with new compiler and ran parallel.

We are using CTest to run the tests in parallel `ctest . -j 10 -O test_logger.txt`. If the tests are ran single threaded `-j 1` all the tests are passing But when ran multi-threaded `-j 10` the tests are failing at random test scenarios. It appears that there could be some static global constants in the code.

For debugging, I though of using Thread sanitizers but they are not supported on 32 bit linux systems. Is it possible to use and how to use `gdb` along with `ctest -j10` multi-thread in order to catch the segfaults or any other way of debugging ?

Comment: Ctest run jobs with sub-processes, does your test program have multiple threads? If the test program reads or writes files, there may be data corruption if multiple test program accesses the same file without a lock. It's a common reason for parallel test fails.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin .. Yes, i found one of the failing test has read/write to file. But many doesn't.

Comment: Does your test program has multiple threads? If they don't use multiple threads, there can't be data races. Does your test have assertion on timer or sleep? Parallel jobs may slow down the test and make some timer related test fails.

Comment: Other similar resources that can be conflict in multiple processes: tcp/udp ports binding, named pipe